# Wordpress SlideDeck2 plugin Confilct with Role Scoper Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have installed Wordpress v3.3.2 then installed the SlideDeck2 plugin. It was working perfectly.

After that I installed Role Scoper plugin Version 1.3.57.

Now slide show (SlideDeck2) on my site is only visible to logged in users, when logged out only iframe is visible and images are not visible. If I disable the Role Scoper plugin then again slide show is visible.

Now slide show is only visible if I am logged in or if the Role Scoper plugin is not active.

How to resolve this conflict? Any Help?

Comment: What if you try WordPress 3.4.2? Or was it a typo in the Question? For user management, I prefer [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/). SlideDeck is a premium plugin, have you asked their support what the issue might be?

Comment: WordPress is now 3.5. Please update, along with Role Scoper (1.3.59) and if necessary SlideDeck2. Then confirm whether or not the issue still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Activate both plugins
2. Open the website in Chrome
3. hit F12 to open up developer tools
4. go to the console window
5. Are there errors being thrown that hint to the problem?
6. Disable Role Scoper
7. Run Steps 2-4
8. Did the errors go away
9. Run steps 1-5 and make the error go away